# how to find the address of a function in a c++ program

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

i need to find the address of func in the stack so that if i provided a 32 long "A" string and then the function address in the stack i would get the Access granted

i remember i did it using `objdump` but i can't seem to figure it out

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void func() 
{ 
     cout << "Access Granted \n";


}

int main()
{
    char buff[20];

    cin >> buff;
    cout << buff;

    return 0;
}
```

i tried immunity debugger but i was not successful

Comment: It sounds like you are relying on a buffer overflow to get a function address. This is officially undefined behavior and therefore platform dependent.

Comment: Stack smashing and similar exploits require great knowledge of the target platform, compiler and its version. Things like stack layout is extremely specific to compiler and version of it. So please tell us what compiler you're using as well as version of both. Also please tell us what you're trying to do, and *why*. Also please read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: i compiled the program using "g++ -g -fno-stack-protector -o out_file in_file.cpp

Answer (score 1):

> how to find the address of a function in a c++ program

You can use the addressof operator to get a function pointer to the function. This pointer stores the address. Note that this cannot be done for non-static member functions because you get a member function pointer rather than a function pointer.

To print the address, you can convert the function pointer to `void*`. Note however that not all systems support this conversion.

Comment: `addressof` is a [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof), right? Not an operator.

Comment: *"Note however that not all systems support this conversion."* I thought `void*` could point to anything.

Comment: @Ayxan `std::addressof` is a function. There is the addressof operator also, which is the unary operator `&`. The difference between them is that the function reinterprets the object as a char, which allows ignoring type specific operator overload. But the function can only be used with objects; not with functions or members. `void*` can only point to objects. It cannot point to members and it can point to functions only on some systems.